# How do you get 2 users from bot.wait_for('reaction_add')?

Tags: python, discord.py

So i have this code:

```
        msg = await channel.send("React to this with ✅ to ready up. ``(0/2)``")
        await msg.add_reaction('✅')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return reaction == '✅' and user.id == initiator or user.id == challenger

        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=check)

        print(user)
```

And when i print the user i want it to print both of them not only 1. Because When they react I want to edit the message that 1 has readied up. I've tried multiple methods such as looping through but none seem to work. Kind Regards.

Comment: I don't really understand your question here. Are you asking "how to wait for 2 users to react" or "how to wait for a reaction from either user1 or user2"?

Comment: What is `initiator` and `challenger`?

Comment: ids of 2 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want both `initiator` and `challenger` to react to your message in a particular order.

First off there is no point in adding a `timeout` if you're not handling the `TimeoutError` accordingly.

A good solution would be to embed your code in a endless loop with a `try:except` clause to catch the timeout error and escape the loop.

In your case you should also define some sort of flag to determine whose turn it is to react:

```
@bot.command
async def my_command(ctx, challenger: discord.Member):
    initiator = ctx.author
    msg = await channel.send("React to this with ✅ to ready up. ``(0/2)``")
    await msg.add_reaction('✅')

    in_turn = initiator
    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=30, check=lambda r, u: r == "✅" and u == in_turn
            turn = 1 if in_turn == initiator else 2
            await msg.edit(f"React to this with ✅ to ready up. ``({turn}/2)``")
            if in_turn == initiator:
                in_turn = challenger
            else:
                break
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send(f"{in_turn.display_name} didn't react in time")
```

Obviously this is just my idea of how this could be implemented, but then you'd have to do something with those reactions (which you didn't clearly state in your question) otherwise the entire task is pointless.